# Transform from laser frame to odom frame using transformation matrix in ROS c++

Tags: transforms, quaternion, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a pioneer3AT with a Hykuoy laser finder. when I run the RosAria, I have 2 frames The odom frame ( fixed frame wich represent the start of the movement) and the baselink frame  which is attached to the body of the robot.

Also, when I run the URG_node I get another frame which is the laser frame.

I added the laser in the same direction of the base_link and I calculated the distance from the base_link frame to the laser frame is [0.206 0 0.16] in meters and I created a static tf transformation between the laser and the baselink as following.

```
  <launch>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="laser_frame" args="0.206 0 0.16 0 0 0 1 base_link laser 100" />
 </launch>
```

My TF tree is as follows: odom -> base_link -> laser

now, in the code, I am reading the sensor_msgs/laserScan msgs as (r, theta) -->

What I want is to do transformation these data from **laser frame to odom frame** ?? how can I do that in ROS (in c++)??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199215/transform-from-laser-frame-to-odom-frame-using-transformation-matrix-in-ros-c++/) by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2014-12-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Get the required tf and transform the pose into the frame you wanted.

check this [using transform](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF#Using_a_Transform) tutorial , it will be helpful.

---

```
// Inside laser callback    

tf::TransformListener listener;
listener.waitForTransform("/laser_frame", "/odom", ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(10.0));

for (int i = 0; i < laser_scan->ranges.size();i++)
{
    range = laser_scan->ranges[i];
    angle  = laser_scan->angle_min +(i * laser_scan->angle_increment);
    
    geometry_msgs::PointStamped laser_point;
    
    laser_point.header.frame_id = "laser_frame";
    laser_point.header.stamp = ros::Time();
    laser_point.point.x = range*cos(angle) ;
    laser_point.point.y = range*sin(angle) ;
    laser_point.point.z = 0.0;
    
    geometry_msgs::PointStamped odom_point;
    
    try{
        listener.transformPoint("odom", laser_point, odom_point);
        
    }
    catch(tf::TransformException& ex){
        ROS_ERROR("Received an exception trying to transform a point : %s", ex.what());
    }
    
    
    //Odom point x,y are in odom frame     
    // Copy or do your stuff 
}
```

---

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5